# How to prove this equality $f(-b)=1-f(b)$

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

I was trying to prove that if $b>0$ then $f(-b)=1-f(b)$.

$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{x} e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} \, dt$.
My idea was trying to take the derivative of both sides and then see the equality but I think that this is totally wrong, so how you would do this?

Comment: I would start to write down the statement that I want to show. This looks like a difference of $\int_{-b}^{b}.$ Can we use symmetries to solve this?

Comment: I think this is only approximately true, and for $b\gg 0.$

Comment: Mr Arrows, if you add more context to your question and add your efforts and attempts, I will help you solve your problem.

Comment: @MariusS.L., actually it is true for any $b\in\Bbb R$ and it is true exactly.